# how to normalize test and train data as both having different different number of rows

Tags: dataframe, machine-learning, scikit-learn, normalization, minmax

I have a dataframe `d` and one of the columns is `price` (Numerical) having 109248 rows. I divided the data into two parts `d_train` and `d_test`. `d_train` has 73196 values and `d_test` has 36052 values. Now to normalize `d_train['price']` and `d_test['price']` i did something like this..

```
price_scalar = Normalizer()
X_train_price = price_scalar.fit_transform(d_train['price'].values.reshape(1, -1)
X_test_price = price_scalar.transform(d_test['price'].values.reshape(1, -1))
```

Now I'm having this issue

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-ba623ca7bafa> in <module>()
3 X_train_price = price_scalar.fit_transform(X_train['price'].values.reshape(1, -1))
----> 4 X_test_price = price_scalar.transform(X_test['price'].values.reshape(1, -1))
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/base.py in _check_n_features(self, X, reset)
394         if n_features != self.n_features_in_:
395             raise ValueError(
397                 f"is expecting {self.n_features_in_} features as input."
398             )
ValueError: X has 36052 features, but Normalizer is expecting 73196 features as input.
```

Doing change: `reshape(-1,1)` instead of `reshape(1,-1)` runs ok but makes all row values of `price` to 1.

Comment: What kind of normalization are you trying to achieve? Normalize features or data points? To an absolute range or statistically (e.g., to have unit standard deviation)?

Comment: I'm jus trying to get values between 0 to 1

Comment: Why on earth you are reshaping in the first place? You speak of values (73196 and 36052), but the error clearly indicates that these are seen as *features* (natural, after reshaping), hence the expected error.  You should not reshape in the code you show here.

Comment: # normalizer.fit(X_train['price'].values)
# this will rise an error Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead: 
# array=[105.22 215.96  96.01 ... 368.98  80.53 709.67].
# Reshape your data either using 
# array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature 
# array.reshape(1, -1)  if it contains a single sample. This is the reason

Answer (score 0):

Reshape(-1, 1) is Ok.The results with 1 is what is expected if you use Normalizer from sklearn:
*Each sample (i.e. each row of the data matrix) with at least one non zero component is rescaled independently of other samples so that its norm (l1, l2 or inf) equals one.*

Comment: then how to to get both between 0 to 1...that's what I'm asking

Comment: Maybe what you need is more something like StandardScaler or MinMaxScaler.

Comment: i tried that...with them also the same issue i have

Comment: If you tried price_scaler = StandardScaler(), without option,, for example, you cannot get output rows with only 1 values as the mean is 0 for train data after fit_transform.

Answer (score 0):

`scikit-learn` always assumes that the data is organized with shape `(n_points, n_features)` (i.e., each row is a data point). Also, from the documentation, `Normalizer` normalizes "samples individually to unit norm". This means that each data point (i.e., row) is normalized, rather than along the column (i.e., all price values).

To normalize the values to the [0, 1] range, you should use the MinMaxScaler with the data reshaped into a column. That is,

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
price_scalar = MinMaxScaler()
X_train_price = price_scalar.fit_transform(d_train['price'].values.reshape(-1, 1))
X_test_price = price_scalar.transform(d_test['price'].values.reshape(-1, 1))
```

It it noteworthy that this does **not** guarantee that the price values in the test set are all within the [0, 1] range. That is the way it should be when learning an ML model, but remember to keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Here, you can directly `fit_transform()` function, instead of `fit()` and `transform()` function separately.

```
price_scalar = Normalizer()
X_train_price = price_scalar.fit_transform(d_train['price'].values.reshape(1, -1)
X_test_price = price_scalar.fit_transform(d_test['price'].values.reshape(1, -1))
```